# Prevent mypy errors in platform dependent python code

Tags: python, windows, cross-platform, mypy

I have something akin to the following piece of python code:

```py
import platform
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    import winreg
    import win32api

def do_cross_platform_thing() -> None:
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        # do some overly complicated windows specific thing with winreg and win32api
    else:
        # do something reasonable for everyone else
```

Now, on linux, `mypy` complains that

- it's missing imports because `win32api` doesn't exist,
- "module has no attribute  ..." because the `winreg` module is
  defined, but basically disabled (all code is behind an 'is windows' check).

Is there any reasonable way to deal with this ? My current solution is

- spamming `# type: ignore` everywhere
- `--ignore-missing-imports`

Are there any better solutions for this?

Comment: import them also if `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`?

Comment: `mypy` supports only `sys.platform` and `sys.version_info()` as platform and version checkers, also not all operations are working. For `sys.version_info` indexing and comparison operations are allowed, for `sys.platform` equality, inequality and `startswith`. Probably something else, but these do for sure. [Docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#version-and-platform-checks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after checking the [Docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#version-and-platform-checks) as @SUTerliakov so kindly suggested,
it seems that i have to change my

```py
if platform.system() == "Windows"
```

to this, semantically identical check:

```py
if sys.platform == "win32"
```

**Only this second version** triggers some magic builtin mypy special case that
identifies this as a platform check and ignores the branch not
applicable to its plattform.